# FileSaver.js - Change Title of Save Dialog Window

Tags: dialog, filesaver.js

I'm using  [file-saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) in an Angular app that is plugged into Electron. Is there any option to change the title of the save dialog window?

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
let blob = ...
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'file.xml');
```

At the moment it shows "`blob:http://localhost:4444/...`", see screenshot below

[image]